# Flutter app is not installing on physical device`

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-test

I'm using my vivo s1(Android 11) for android app development. before the update when I run apps via USB cable, its works well but after the update when I run the app it just shows a blank white screen (as shown in the picture below). I think developer option giving me a problem because when I run the same app on my friend's phone(Redmi note 8 pro) its works properly. Can anyone please help me with the settings of developer option to install apps via USB because "install apps via USB" option is now not available in the developer option.

CONSOLE:
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1907 19 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...

Its stuck in the installing of app and my device just show the white screen (shown below).

[the white screen of my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0FTZ.jpg)

Comment: enable developer options and then enable USB debugging.

Comment: already enabled

Comment: check minimum SDK version in the manifest and make sure it is compatible with your device.

Comment: can you please explain it a little more

Comment: @Usama Ali, I think Benyamin meant you need to make sure that the version of your device is greater than or equal to the minSdk version specified in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yes, my device version is greater than the minSDK version.